# .Net InstallShield - Creates broken shortcuts

Tags: installshield, installshield-le, installshield-2013

I've got 2 projects in my solution.

1. The one is a small win forms project, and
2. the other, a InstallShield Limited Edition project.

Everything works fine & installs correctly for the most part. The desktop and start menu shortut's get created also with the correct icon... except that that the target & start in properties are blank... and thus the shortcuts are useless.

Normally target should have the reference to the executable, but it seems to be populated with my project name :/

I'm not too sure how I can go about debugging this? Or what would be causing the problem?

[image]

Comment: That appears to be exactly what MSI's "advertised" shortcuts look like, just from comparing to some other. They do in general work - they are just different and may cause repair if a component in the target feature has been damaged. See the installer property here to turn them off http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368297(v=vs.85).aspx  DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I started going going through the sub steps in the Installer project.

[image]

Under the 3rd node - **Configure the Target System**, there is a **Shortcuts/Folders** item.

Upon opening you'll see a tree view of where the shortcuts will be created. I selected the desktop shortcut, and noticed that the working directory was not set. I changed it to point to `[INSTALLDIR]`

This fixed the problem for me

[image]